# X-Frame-Options PHP If Statement

Tags: php

$header equals 'DENY' but result will not echo '0'. It only echoes '1'. What is wrong with my code? Is it due to X-Frame-Options?

```
<?php 

$url = "http://www.chiefaircraft.com/";
$header = get_headers($url, 1);

$header = $header["X-Frame-Options"];


if (DENY == $header ) {

    $result = "0";

}

else {
    $result = "1";
}

echo $result;
echo "<br>";
echo $header;
// or 'SAMEORIGIN' or 'ALLOW-FROM'
?>
```

Comment: `var_dump($header)`, is it really precisely the value you expect? Also, `DENY`… a constant? Use `'DENY'` instead.

Comment: @deceze when I do var_dump($header) it echoes:   string(10) "DENY "

Comment: What I want is a variable to post to data base if a link is iframe allowed or not.  If iframe is not allowed $header["X-Frame-Options"] will echo: DENY  or SAMEORIGIN or ALLOW-FROM.  For some reason I can't get it to work with this if statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, The thing which you are trying will not work because if you do `strlen($header)` then it will give you `10`, there are some trailing spaces, which you have to avoid.

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$url = "http://www.chiefaircraft.com/";
$header = get_headers($url, 1);
$header = $header["X-Frame-Options"];
if (strpos($header, "DENY")===0)//added this line.
{
    $result = "0";
} else
{
    $result = "1";
}
echo $result;
```

**Output:** `0`

Comment: Thank you! Worked like a charm. Didn't realize it had spaces. Much appreciated.

Comment: Is there a way I can add SAMEORIGIN or ALLOW-FROM to the variables that provide result=0 too?  Ideally I am looking for:  DENY or SAMEORIGIN or ALLOW-FROM.

Comment: @Scott Sorry i was not here, Yes sure i will help you in that as well..

Comment: @Scott Do you want to check it for `DENY`, `SAMEORIGIN ` and `ALLOW-FROM`?

Comment: Yes. If it is any of those 3 options I would like the result to be zero.  Thank you.

Comment: @Scott Try this if else `if (stristr($header, "DENY") || stristr($header, "SAMEORIGIN") || stristr($header, "ALLOW-FROM") )
{
    $result = "0";
} else
{
    $result = "1";
}` like this https://eval.in/803905

Comment: Thank you very much. Worked great.  You really helped me out!

Comment: @Scott welcome friend... :) no issues i will help you further if you got any issues.. no worries..

Answer (score 0):

It won't work unless you define `DENY` as a constant, you are trying to compare `DENY` as constant, compare as string (wrap `DENY` in quotes) if you don't have constant `DENY`,

```
if ("DENY" == trim($header) ) { //remove extra spaces
...
```

Comment: I'll point out that `DENY` *would* work even as a bare string/constant, ***iif*** there's no actual constant `DENY` defined somewhere…

Comment: I still get the same problem with DENY in quotes ("DENY").

Comment: @Scott what does var_dump($header); show..? Can you add that in question..

Comment: @Scott the "X-Frame-Options" returns DENY with extra spaces, so you could trim the variable and compare against string "DENY"

Comment: Thanks Sudhir.  I didn't realize it had spaces in the string.